# Access objects in array list

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am trying to access objects an arraylist using javascript, the arraylist is:

```
membersList:{
    "kind":"admin#directory#users",
    "users":[{"orgUnitPath":"/",
        "isMailboxSetup":true,
        "id":"1076823423424234",
        "isAdmin":false,
        "suspended":false,
        "isDelegatedAdmin":false,
        "isEnforcedIn2Sv":false,
        "etag":"\"npJcgsdfsadfsfsff\"",
        "ipWhitelisted":false,"changePasswordAtNextLogin":true,
        "customerId":"C01looera",
        "includeInGlobalAddressList":true,
        "lastLoginTime":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "primaryEmail":"ilda.donofrio@domain.org",
        "isEnrolledIn2Sv":false,"kind":"admin#directory#user",
        "name":{"givenName":"ilda",
            "familyName":"donofrio",
            "fullName":"ilda donofrio"},
            "creationTime":"2018-06-10T11:56:45.000Z",
            "emails":[{"address":"ilda.donofrio@domain.org",
            "primary":true}],
            "agreedToTerms":true
            }],
        "etag":"\"npJcgsdfsadfsfsff/npJcgsdfsadfsfsff\"

    }
```

I am trying to access the `primary email` from this list for which I wrote a code i.e

```
for (var j in membersList) {
       var member = membersList[j];
       Logger.log('member Email:' + member);
    }
```

which just returns me

```
[18-06-12 15:39:55:982 EDT] member Email:admin#directory#users

[18-06-12 15:39:55:982 EDT] member Email:{"orgUnitPath":"/","isMailboxSetup":true,"id":"1076823423424234","isAdmin":false,"suspended":false,"isDelegatedAdmin":false,"isEnforcedIn2Sv":false,"etag":"\"npJcgsdfsadfsfsff\"","ipWhitelisted":false,"changePasswordAtNextLogin":false,"customerId":"C01looera","includeInGlobalAddressList":true,"lastLoginTime":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","primaryEmail":"ilda.donofrio@domain.org","isEnrolledIn2Sv":false,"kind":"admin#directory#user","name":{"givenName":"ilda","familyName":"donofrio","fullName":"ilda donofrio"},"creationTime":"2018-06-10T11:56:45.000Z","emails":[{"address":"ilda.donofrio@domain.org","primary":true}],"agreedToTerms":true}

[18-06-12 15:39:55:983 EDT] member Email:"npJcgsdfsadfsfsff/npJcgsdfsadfsfsff\"
```

When I tried with:

```
Logger.log('member Email:' + member.primaryEmail);
```

Its throwing:

```
[18-06-12 16:02:53:630 EDT] member Email:undefined
[18-06-12 16:02:53:630 EDT] member Email:undefined
[18-06-12 16:02:53:631 EDT] member Email:undefined
```

Is there a way to extract the value of just the `primaryEmail` using the script? I am a newbie to javascript and google scripts so please pardon me if its a stupid question.

Comment: That is not an "array list". That is one key of an object that stores another object as the value of that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer that worked for me in google apps script was:

```
for (var j in membersList) {
       var member = membersList[j];
       for (var k in member){        
         var user =  member[k];
         var memberEmail = user.primaryEmail;
         var lastLoginTime = user.lastLoginTime;
       } 
    }
    Logger.log('member Email:' + memberEmail);
    Logger.log('last Login Time:' + lastLoginTime);
```

I tried every method that was posted here, but was unsuccessful but as @AllenG quoted, i just had to iterate over over all of the `users` in the member list object. Thank you so much for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over all of the `users` in the member list object, and then retrieve each user's `primaryEmail`. Currently, you are iterating over all of the attributes of the `membersList` object (i.e. the keys, one of them being `users`).

As an example:

```
membersList['users'].forEach((user) => {
  Logger.log('member Email: ' + user['primaryEmail']);
}
```

The manner of iteration is up to you, I just tend to use `.forEach` in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `membersList.users[0].primaryEmail` to access the primary email.

Also, on the last bit (`"etag":"\"npJcgsdfsadfsfsff/npJcgsdfsadfsfsff\"`) the last `\` exits the string but it shouldn't, so try removing it.

```js
var membersList = {
    "kind":"admin#directory#users",
    "users":[{"orgUnitPath":"/",
        "isMailboxSetup":true,
        "id":"1076823423424234",
        "isAdmin":false,
        "suspended":false,
        "isDelegatedAdmin":false,
        "isEnforcedIn2Sv":false,
        "etag":"\"npJcgsdfsadfsfsff\"",
        "ipWhitelisted":false,"changePasswordAtNextLogin":true,
        "customerId":"C01looera",
        "includeInGlobalAddressList":true,
        "lastLoginTime":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "primaryEmail":"ilda.donofrio@domain.org",
        "isEnrolledIn2Sv":false,"kind":"admin#directory#user",
        "name":{"givenName":"ilda",
            "familyName":"donofrio",
            "fullName":"ilda donofrio"},
            "creationTime":"2018-06-10T11:56:45.000Z",
            "emails":[{"address":"ilda.donofrio@domain.org",
            "primary":true}],
            "agreedToTerms":true
            }],
        "etag":"\"npJcgsdfsadfsfsff/npJcgsdfsadfsfsff"

    }
    
console.log(membersList.users[0].primaryEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

To access primaryEmail, try using `membersList["users"]["primaryEmail"]`